# Windows 32bit -- Geth/Parity

Tags: go-ethereum, parity

Hey is it possible to run Geth/Parity + mine on a Windows 32bit machine? I'm having trouble finding anything.

Comment: There are no 32bit builds available yet. But I expect releases for all platforms and architectures soon(tm).

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm gonna come out of the stone era and make the upgrade.